# Querydsl - filter on Left join with subquery

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, java-8, querydsl, type-safety

I have one of the complex query dynamically generated through Querydsl predicate and JPQL. I am also using the Q classes.

I am able to generate the following query by passing a predicate to the JPA repository.

```
select company0_.id as id1_18_,
   company0_.name as name2_18_
from company company0_
left outer join companyAddress companyadd1_ on company0_.id=companyadd1_.company_id
where company0_.id in
    (select companyadd2_.company_id
     from companyAddress companyadd2_
     where companyadd2_.address_type='1')
order by companyadd1_.addressline1;
```

but I want the query mentioned below

```
select company0_.id as id1_18_,
   company0_.name as name2_18_
from company company0_
left outer join companyAddress companyadd1_ on company0_.id=companyadd1_.company_id
and companyadd1_.status = 'Active' -- New added(Failed to implement this)
where company0_.id in
    (select companyadd2_.company_id
     from companyAddress companyadd2_
     where companyadd2_.address_type='1'
     and and companyadd2_.status = 'Active') -- New Added(I am able to achieve this)
order by companyadd1_.addressline1;
```

We are using following kind of code, I can not possibly to share exact code due to security concern but you can help me by providing basic structure or code to achieve this.

```
final JPQLQuery<QCompanyAlias> subQuery = new JPAQuery<>();
        BooleanExpression exp = null;
        QueryBase<?> q = (QueryBase<?>) subQuery.from(qCompanyAddress);
        if (requestMap.containsKey(CompanyQueryConstants.ADDRESS_TYPE)) {
            BooleanExpression addrExp = null;
            for (String addressType : addressTypes) {
                if (addrExp == null) {
                    addrExp = qCompanyAddress.addressType.addressTypeCode.eq(addressType);
                } else {
                    addrExp = addrExp.or(qCompanyAddress.addressType.addressTypeCode.eq(addressType));
                }
            }
            exp = addrExp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add join on two conditions use

```
    new JPAQuery(em)
        .from(qCompany)
        .leftJoin(qCompany, qCompanyAddress.company)       
        .on(
            qCompany.id.eq(qCompanyAddress.company.id)
            .and(qCompanyAddress.status.eq(status))
        );
```

For subquery try to use this

```
final JPQLQuery<QCompanyAlias> subQuery = new JPAQuery<>();
        BooleanExpression exp = null;
        QueryBase<?> q = (QueryBase<?>) subQuery.from(qCompanyAddress);
        if (requestMap.containsKey(CompanyQueryConstants.ADDRESS_TYPE)) {
            BooleanExpression addrExp = null;
            for (String addressType : addressTypes) {
                if (addrExp == null) {
                    addrExp = qCompanyAddress.addressType.addressTypeCode.eq(addressType);
                } else {
                    addrExp = addrExp.or(qCompanyAddress.addressType.addressTypeCode.eq(addressType));
                }
            }
            exp = addrExp;
        }

        BooleanExpression statusExp = qCompanyAddress.status.eq(status);

        if(exp == null) {
            exp = statusExp;
        } else {
            exp = statusExp.and(exp);
        }
```

But in your case I can't understand the reason for filtering by `status` twice. Subquery filtering should be enought. I suspect that you can achieve the same result without subquery. It depends on your entities.